# win32process.CreateProcess cannot set size and location of the executed programme

Tags: python, pywin32, win32-process

I am testing win32process.CreateProcess to execute an external programme from python by specified size and location of the executed programme with this snippet

```
import win32process,win32con

StartupInfo = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
StartupInfo.dwFlags = (win32con.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES ^
                  win32con.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW)

StartupInfo.dwX, StartupInfo.dwY = (50,50)
StartupInfo.dwFlags ^= win32con.STARTF_USEPOSITION

StartupInfo.dwXSize, StartupInfo.dwYSize = (100,100)
StartupInfo.dwFlags ^= win32con.STARTF_USESIZE

StartupInfo.wShowWindow = 1

procHandles = win32process.CreateProcess(None, # appName
              'explorer',  # commandLine
              None,  # processAttributes
              None, # threadAttributes
              1,  # bInheritHandles
              win32process.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,  # dwCreationFlags
              None,  # newEnvironment
              None,  # currentDirectory
              StartupInfo)  # startupinfo
```

The programme can be executed but without any effect from `StartupInfo`.
What did I do wrong?